# Сформировать запрос к БД под Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Надо вытащить client_id из БД. Код подключения к бд написал, но как сформировать запрос не понимаю. Дайте пожалуйста подсказку или где прочитать про это.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MyTestBD {
    private static final String login = "billing";
    private static final String password = "billing";
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1:3306/billing";
    private Connection connection;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyTestBD myTestBD = new MyTestBD();
        myTestBD.connect();
        //какой-то код
        myTestBD.close();
    }

    //Добавляет все client_id в TreeSet
    public void clientIdList(){
        TreeSet<Integer> clientId = new TreeSet<>();
    }


    public Connection connect(){
        try{
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,login,password);
            System.out.println("Connection successful!");
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Ooops! Try again...");
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public void disconnect() {
            try {
                connection.close();
                connection = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("No connection! Try again...");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно? Как пользоваться JDBC или как составлять SQL-запросы?

Comment: Как составлять запросы, изучение sql хромает(

Comment: [Мартин Грабер "SQL для простых смертных"](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/24939188/)